# Question not posted because the title isn't capitalized, wrongly indicates the problem is with the question body

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

I've tried asking a question on Stack Overflow and it wasn't approved with the following error

> this question body does not meet our quality standards. please make sure that it completely describes your problem - including what you have already tried - and is written using proper grammar.

I did not manage to find out why it isn't approved so I asked support (through the contact-us form). It turned out that the problem wasn't in the body, but in the title (it wasn't capitalized).

This was the post:
[Command Line Arguments vs Input - What's the Difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53571637/command-line-arguments-vs-input-whats-the-difference/53571638#53571638)

I tried to post it as it is now, excluding the title which was not capitalized.
It is a bug because the error indicates that the problem is with the question body, when the problem is with the question title.

(I'm not asking anything here, just reporting a bug.)

Comment: You need to somehow give us an idea of what you tried to post.

Answer (score 12):

The title is only *one part* of the entire check. A faulty title *could* contribute to the warning, but the body of the question is almost always the culprit. In your case, I could see why your question would be triggering the warning - none of your sentences there are capitalized at the first word when they should be and you definitely should fix that. Likely what happened is that putting a bunch of capitals in the title caused the overall number of capitals in the title + body to be sufficient enough to pass the check, even though that's not where the capitals were needed.

Long story short: you didn't find a bug. You found a way to bypass the check by improving something else, but your question body still needs improvement and the warning was correctly triggering for you.

Comment: Maybe the spell check score needs to be weighted separately for both body and title and take the minimum.

Comment: It *is* a bit awkward when the error specifically cites the question body as the problem, and fixing the title made the error go away. Perhaps the error needs rewording?

Comment: @MadaraUchiha I'm more with Braiam, but I'd go further. Just have separate checks for title and the body. Why on God's green Earth would we want the author to only fix one of them?

Comment: @jpmc26 I'd agree with you if the error in question gave off actionable feedback on specifically what's wrong, but it does not, in my opinion, do a good enough job at it.